# How to get cpuid using inline assembly in powerpc?

Tags: c++, gcc, inline-assembly, powerpc, cpuid

I am trying compile a c++ code. but I am getting an error on power8 architecture. which is working fine in x86_64 architectures. below is the error I am getting.

```
  error: impossible register constraint in 'asm'
          : "a"(func));
                      ^
```

Below is the code block where I am getting that error.

```
static INLINE void cpuid(int *dest, int func)
{
        __asm__ volatile("cpuid"
                                 : "=a"(dest[0]), "=b"(dest[1]), "=c"(dest[2]), "=d"(dest[3])
                                 : "a"(func));
}
```

is something is wrong in this code or I am missing something?

Or is there any other way to get the cpu id?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "the cpu id" - Actually, the CPUID instruction allows you to retrieve a LOT of information on the x86, depending on the value specified in 'func'.  How you would work around this depends on what information you are trying to retrieve, and what you intend to do with it.  Also, this question might be considered a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17948969/2189500).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, `cpuid` is an instruction in x86-64 (AMD64 / EMT64) and later x86 (IA32) processors, and has nothing to do with powerpc. As far as I know, there's no equivalent of such an instruction for powerpc (at least not unprivileged instructions) mandated by the powerpc specification, so operating systems have their own approaches.

On some systems, e.g., BSD variants, this might be as simple as: `sysctl <option>`

You could have a look at the strategies used by `gcc` to determine the `powerpc` and `power` processor versions for different *operating systems*:

From the current `gcc-8.1.0` source: [`driver-powerpcspe.c`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/powerpcspe/driver-powerpcspe.c;h=cf3ef94dcb0fa710093e91a9b7455e464036a733;hb=af8bbdf198a7cd619efd7c9a7aef2f86d5590aae), [`driver-rs6000.c`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/rs6000/driver-rs6000.c;h=972099a47ee81f31d8b9a0eeb53fb782de1a6e77;hb=af8bbdf198a7cd619efd7c9a7aef2f86d5590aae) might provide some code you can adapt.

Another interesting source might be the autotools infrastructure for the [GMP library](https://gmplib.org); specifically, the top-level `config.guess` and `configure.ac` files.

---

Also: `gcc -march=native -E -dM - < /dev/null` on a power[pc] host might allow you to grep for a CPU and/or subtype string.

Answer (score 1):

`cpuid` is a x86_64 thing. There's no such thing on Power.

Comment: Thanks for replying @jesper. if there is no such thing in Power, how this kind of problems will be handled. we just ignore them or any other workarounds?

Comment: How it is "handled" depends on what you are doing.  If the purpose of the program is to print out information about the CPU, then "ignoring" probably isn't the right answer.  See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17948969/2189500).